# EXECUTE Permission Denied on Scalar UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working in SSMS 2008.  I have created a scalar UDF with dbo as the schema owner.  (No error was thrown, and I confirmed that the function was created.)  I am trying to grant the execute command on it with:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[some_function] TO Public
```

However, SQL throws the following error:

> Cannot find the object 'some_function, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I don't understand why I don't have permission on this.  Can somebody please explain?

Comment: (You probably already tried this, but I will ask anyway) Did you create the UDF in a specific DB?  Maybe you are in Master, or the UDF was created in Master.  (I do that all of the time).  Have you tried explicitly specifying the DB in the Grant statement?

Comment: Are you a SA?  Are you sure you have Grant permissions in your current DB? (can you grant permissions on other objects, UDFs, Tables?)